# Visual Studio error with designer and project launch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have re-installed windows today Windows 8 Professional.
Have installed Visual Studio 2012 without any errors or problems.
Enabled Hyper V.

But i cant see designer it shows only blank white page:

[image]

And when i Launch any Windows Store project on Local Machine it shows Splash screen and the blue screen:

[image]

And when i try running it on simulator i see this:

[image]

**What is the problem? and how to fix it? 
P.S. Before all worked fine**

Visual Studio updating, repairing and reinstalling didn't help

Comment: I have the same problem with windows 8.1 too. Been searching for a month even re formatting the computer even didn't work. Now I can't even use Visual studio-2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how, but updating to Windows 8.1 solved the problem